# Portal 2's Peer Review not working

Tags: xbox-360, portal-2, portal-2-peer-review

I play Portal 2 on Xbox 360 and downloaded the Peer Review Dlc. I saved it to an external device (usb stick) where I keep alot of my game progress and data.

At the time I was about half way through the Coop mode and knew that I had to complete it to play the dlc. Later on, me and my friend finished the story (locally) and we were trying to find out how to get to the dlc.

I've seen that you need to get to the newest pillar in the hub, but when we looked at it it wasn't opening up so we couldn't portal in. It stayed closed and there is no visible way to get inside.

We've tried reloading the game and redownloading the Dlc but nothing has changed.

Please help!

[image: The hub - as you can see the pillar is not open and cannot be entered. AAAARGHH!!]

Answer (score 2):

It took a good long time for to find this as well. Go into the co-op hub where you can see the big-screen display that shows things like steps taken. Stand in the center of the main platform and look at the board. The light bridge should be ramping down in front of you from right to left. Turn 90 degrees to the right; you should see the hanging surfaces that you portal into in order to fall on the bouncy plate. From here, you should be able to see into a hollow column on the right with a door and a couple buttons visible. Put a portal in and there and go!